# Error 'Character set '#255' is not a compiled character set and is not specified mySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, database-replication

Okay, I've hit a brick wall and have run out of ideas.

```
Master:  8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 

Slave:  5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log
```

Getting error with `show slave status\G`:

```
Last_SQL_Errno: 22
Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Character set '#255' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file' on query. Default database: 'db'. Query: 'BEGIN'
```

I'm migrating my master server to a new host, which means that it's had lots of updates. The slave is the same previously used server and hasn't changed.

I've tried

- `reset slave all` & readding `change master to`
- updating both master and slave my.cnf files to include:

  [client]
  default-character-set=utf8

  [mysqld]
  character-set-server=utf8
  collation-server=utf8_unicode_c
- manually updating the db collation on both to utf8

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: The [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-upgrade.html) say that the slave needs to be upgraded BEFORE the master. Go back to your previous working setup and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There are gobs of new collations on 8.0.  You must use the subset that is available on 5.7 when replicating (either direction).

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on the table in question.

But, I see that it may be `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`?  In that case, file a bug report:  bugs.mysql.com  and hope that they don't tell you to get lost because of mixing 8.0 and pre-8.0 across replication.

Comment: And they most likely will say to get lost because the docs say now (and have said basically forever) that you have to upgrade the replication slaves first.